# FluentValidation Command Validator not registered by AutoFac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, autofac, fluentvalidation

I've been struggling with an issue for a while now. I am building a project based on the eShopOnContainers GitHub project [See Here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers). My project is running on asp.net core 2.2 and I am using

MediatR 6.0,

- MediatR 6.0
- MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 6.0.1
- FluentValidation.AspNetCore 8.1.2
- Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection 4.3.1

I am using MediatR commands that are handled by a command handler, and through many articles, along with the eShopOnContainers sample online, I've implemented a `ValidatorBehavior` class that implements `IPipelineBehavior`.

```
public class ValidatorBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidatorBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(request);
        var failures = _validators
            .Select(v => v.Validate(context))
            .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
            .Where(error => error != null)
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Any())
        {
            throw new PlanningDomainException(
                $"Command Validation Errors for type {typeof(TRequest).Name}", new ValidationException("Validation exception", failures));
        }

        var response = await next();
        return response;
    }
}
```

I've also included a MediatorModule, just as implemented in the sample project.

```
public class MediatorModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetType().Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        // Get the assembly name
        var assembly = typeof(Startup).GetType().Assembly;

        // Register all the Command classes (they implement IRequestHandler) in assembly holding the Commands
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));

        // Register the DomainEventHandler classes (they implement INotificationHandler<>) 
        // in assembly holding the Domain Events
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(INotificationHandler<>));

        // Register the Command's Validators (Validators based on FluentValidation library)
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IValidator<>)))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(context =>
        {
            var componentContext = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return t => { object o; return componentContext.TryResolve(t, out o) ? o : null; };
        });

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>)).As(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>));
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ValidatorBehavior<,>)).As(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>));
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(TransactionBehaviour<,>)).As(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>));

    }
}
```

My test controller is:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ApplicationsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public ApplicationsController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody]ApplicationCreateCommand command, [FromHeader(Name = "x-requestid")] string requestId)
    {
        var c = await _mediator.Send(command);
        return c ? Ok() : (IActionResult)BadRequest();
    }
}
```

I have the following issues:

1. Whenever I attempt to call this API I get the following error:

   Cannot resolve parameter 'MediatR.IMediator mediator' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MediatR.IMediator)'.

I am solving this by adding mediator as a service using `.AddMediatR()` even though in the sample project it is never added like that.

2. Once I add the mediatr, the API runs correctly and the command is being send and the command handled is handling it correctly. Meanwhile, the `ValidatorBehavior` 
   is being called correctly, but the CommandValidator is not present. The `_validators` list is actually empty so no validation is being made.

I've also set up break points in the command validator but none are being hit.

This is my command validator:

```
public class ApplicationCreateCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<ApplicationCreateCommand>
{
    public ApplicationCreateCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(cmd => cmd.CategoryType).NotEmpty().Must(BeValidCategoryType).WithMessage("The category type is not valid.");
        RuleFor(cmd => cmd.CompetitionId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The competition id must be specified.");
        RuleFor(cmd => cmd.ParticipantId).NotEmpty().WithMessage("The participant id must be specified.");
    }

    private bool BeValidCategoryType(int categoryType)
    {
        return categoryType != 0;
    }
}
```

Everything should work fine! I do not understand why it wouldn't. Maybe I am not loading the command validators correctly in autofac, however, every sample code I found online point to the same registration method:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IValidator<>)))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I have the entire source code for this project on my git hub account if you would like to take a closer look. [This is the API](https://github.com/lakylekidd/ApollonSkatingService/tree/master/Planning.API).

Can anybody help me understand what I'm doing wrong? It's been driving me nuts these past few days.

Comment: Did this get resolved? I am facing the exact same issue and am using the same eshoponcontainer project as well. Could you please let me know if this was resolved?

Comment: Hey man. No nobody replied to this so what I did instead was to add every validation individually as a patchy fix.

Comment: @BillyVlachos, Based on your detailed question I was able to resolve my own problem, thank you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have similar configuration as yours. Only difference I can find is below lines in my start.cs file

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
                {
                    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<MediatorModule>();
                    fv.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;
                }
            );
}
```

Comment: Yes! After all this time, you were the first one to give me the solution! Thank you so much. I was missing this piece of code!

Comment: I am glad that I could help.